# Javascript not enabling html forms

Tags: javascript, html

It has been ages i don't work anything in JS, i'm trying to do with a select enable another html form when certain selected option is being chosen. this is my script:

```
<script>
function Activar() {


var e = document.getElementById('perm_tipo');
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    if(strUser=="familiar"){

    document.getElementById('paciente').disabled = false;
    }else{

    document.getElementById('paciente').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

i have those html select inside a form, i think that could be the problem but checking on google seems that's should'nt be an issue.

here is my html code:

```
<form id="registro" action="admin_panel.php" method="post">  
<table border="0">
      <tr>
      <td>Tipo de permiso</td>
      <td>
            <select name="perm_tipo"  onchange="Activar()">
            <?php
                permiso();
                ?>
            </select>

        <br>
      </td>
       <td>Paciente</td>
      <td>
            <select id="paciente" disabled>
            <?php
                pacientes();
                ?>
            </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit"  value="Registrar usuario"/><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the php functions just fill the select options with data from some database, no big deal there, they work, no problem there.

Comment: And what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `getElementById`, you should use 'id' instead of 'name' in the 'select' element.

```
<select id="perm_tipo"  onchange="Activar()">
....
</select>
```

More refactor: you can pass the DOM element itself in the event listener and you don't have to do `var e = document.getElementById('perm_tipo');` in the first place

```
<select name="perm_tipo"  onchange="Activar(this)">
 ....
</select>

<script>
  function Activar(e) {
   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

   if(strUser=="familiar")
     document.getElementById('paciente').disabled = false;
   else
     document.getElementById('paciente').disabled = true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: oh, i see, i feel like a moron X\